# Kepler's laws of planetary motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, asteroids, comets

I was going through some questions and I found that although asteroids obey Kepler's law of planetary motion but comets don't. I searched on the internet and it's given that comets do obey the laws but in my textbook it's given the opposite for comets. Shouldn't the Kepler's law be applicable to both of them? I am not able to get an accurate answer.

Comment: What textbook is this?

Answer (score 4):

Let's look and see. Keep in mind that Kepler's Laws were strictly observational behaviors of planets (and eventually moons), not theoretical explanations of the behavior. Newton was the first to determine an explanation for the behaviors.

1. Kepler's Law of Ellipses (1st Law): Planets move in elliptical paths around the Sun with the Sun at a focus of the ellipse.

Some comets are repeating comets, and they are on elliptical paths. These comets have a total mechanical energy (gravitational potential energy of comet and Sun plus kinetic energy) that is negative:$$-\frac{GM_Sm_C}{r}+\frac{1}{2}m_Cv_C^2 <0.$$
If they are on an elliptical path around the Sun, the Sun will be at a focus. If, however, the total mechanical energy is zero or positive, the comet is **not** on an elliptical path, and doesn't follow Kepler's 1st Law.

2. Kepler's Law of Equal Areas, or the 2nd Law: A line from the Sun to the planet will sweep out equal areas in equal amounts of time.

Thanks to Newton's eventual explanation of gravitational forces, this behavior is explained by conservation of angular momentum. Because comets, whether elliptical, parabolic, or hyperbolic, move under the primary influence of the Sun's gravitational field, and their angular momentum remains constant. That means that comets, unless affected by some nearby planet like Jupiter, will follow Kepler's 2nd Law.

A nearby planetary effect will change the angular momentum of the comet and set it on a different orbit, changing the time behavior of the comet.

3. Kepler's Harmonic Law or 3rd Law - The square of the period of revolution of a planet around the Sun is proportional to the cube of the semi-major axis length of the elliptical orbit.

As stated in the examination of the 1st Law, some comets don't follow an elliptical path. In those cases, there is no revolutionary period and no semi-major axis. One might say that the semi-major axis is infinite, in which case the period is infinite. In that case, the law is true. On the other hand, if you can't define a semi-major axis, then you can't apply the 3rd Law. So, it's a matter of interpretation about "obeying" the 3rd law.

Comment: Comets tend to be volatile, and lose mass when they approach the Sun, which affects their mechanical energy.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take [Kepler's laws from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion#Formulary)

1. The orbit of every planet is an ellipse with the Sun
   at one of the two foci.
   Or mathematically: $$r=\frac{p}{1+\epsilon\cos\theta} \tag{K1}$$
   where $r$ is the radius at angle $\theta$,
   $p$ is the semi-latus rectum (the fancy name for the radius
   at angle $90°$), and $\epsilon$ is the eccentricity.
2. A line joining a planet and the Sun sweeps out equal areas
   during equal intervals of time.
   Or mathematically: $$\frac{dA}{dt}=\text{const}=\frac{A}{T} \tag{K2}$$
   where $dA$ is the area swept over in time interval $dt$,
   $A$ is the total ellipse area, and $T$ is the orbital period.
3. The ratio of the square of an object's orbital period with the cube
   of the semi-major axis of its orbit is the same for all objects
   orbiting the same primary.
   Or mathematically: $$\frac{a^3}{T^2}=\frac{GM}{4\pi^2} \tag{K3}$$
   where $G$ is Newton's gravitational constant, and $M$ is the mass
   of the sun.

The 1st law is already applicable also for comets on parabolic and
hyperbolic trajectories. You just need to replace the word "[ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse)"
by "[conic section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section)", and allow also for $\epsilon \ge 1$.

The main problem is the 3rd law, because it uses semi-major axis ($a$) and
orbital period ($T$), which don't make sense for comets on parabolic or
hyperbolic trajectories. Therefore let's try to reformulate it without
using $a$ and $T$. For an [ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse) we have some geometric relations
between semi-major axis ($a$), semi-latus rectum ($p$), area ($A$),
and eccentricity ($\epsilon$).
$$p=a(1-\epsilon^2)$$
$$A=\pi a^2\sqrt{1-\epsilon^2}$$

Solving (K3) for $T$ we get
$$T=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{a^3}{GM}}$$
Inserting this $T$ and $A$ into the right-hand side of (K2) we get
$$\frac{dA}{dt}
  = \frac{A}{T}
  = \frac{\pi a^2\sqrt{1-\epsilon^2}}{2\pi\sqrt{\frac{a^3}{GM}}}
  = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{GMa(1-\epsilon^2)}
  = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{GMp}$$

So the single equation
$$\frac{dA}{dt}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{GMp}$$
is fully equivalent to (K2) and (K3) together,
but now with the advantage of being applicable not only for elliptic,
but also for parabolic and hyperbolic trajectories.

So in this sense Kepler's laws apply also to comets with parabolic
and hyperbolic trajectories.